# How do I know when bind variables are required?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a simple trigger that uses the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER started
BEFORE UPDATE OF mgr_start_date ON department
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.mgr_start_date < old.mgr_start_date)
BEGIN
    :new.mgr_start_date := :old.mgr_start_date;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rejected backdate of mgr_start_date.');
END;
```

Removing any colon from the assignment statement will throw an error when compiled that the variable must be declared. My understanding is that these colons are for "bind variables" and that the usage of these types of variables removes the need to re-parse the entire statement each time. Why are bind variables required in this case? Why is the equals sign treated as a variable?

Comment: Hi, perhaps this might be of interest http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/use_vars.html

Comment: This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E). In this context the `:new` and `:old` are pseudorecords, not normal bind variables.